# Asp.net core, Angular 2. CookieAuth issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, angular, .net-core

I've got a asp.net-core and Angular 2 application that uses CookieAuthentication.

Everything is working as expected if the user is not signed in. I get a 401 status code back from the web api when a users tries to access a protected resource.

```
    [HttpGet("[action]")]
    [Authorize(Policy = "AdminOnly")]
    public IEnumerable<WeatherForecast> WeatherForecasts()
    {

    }
```

When the authentication passes I run the **SignInAsync** method:

```
        var claims = new[] {new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "Admin")};
        var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
        HttpContext.Authentication.SignInAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
                                               new ClaimsPrincipal(identity),
                                               new AuthenticationProperties() { IsPersistent = false });
```

***That is when I get the following error:***

> fail:
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware[0]
>         An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request System.InvalidOperationException: **No service for type
>   'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.ISecurityStampValidator' has been
>   registered.**    at
>   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService(IServiceProvider
>   provider, Type serviceType)    at
>   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService[T](IServiceProvider
>   provider)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.SecurityStampValidator.ValidatePrincipalAsync(CookieValidatePrincipalContext
>   context)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationHandler.d__12.MoveNext()

My startup.cs is configured as :

```
    public class Startup
    {
    public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
            .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true)
            .AddEnvironmentVariables();
        Configuration = builder.Build();
    }
    public IConfigurationRoot Configuration { get; }
    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddAuthentication();
        // Polices
        services.AddAuthorization(options =>
        {
            // inline policies
            options.AddPolicy("AdminOnly", policy =>
            {
                policy.RequireClaim(ClaimTypes.Role, "Admin");
            });
        });
        // Add framework services.
        services.AddMvc();
    }
    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        loggerFactory.AddConsole(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
        loggerFactory.AddDebug();
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            app.UseWebpackDevMiddleware(new WebpackDevMiddlewareOptions
            {
                HotModuleReplacement = true
            });
        }
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AutomaticAuthenticate = true,
            AutomaticChallenge = true,
            //Don't redirect to /Account/Login.
            Events = new CookieAuthenticationEvents
            {
                OnValidatePrincipal = SecurityStampValidator.ValidatePrincipalAsync,
                OnRedirectToLogin = ctx =>
                {
                    // If request comming from web api
                    // always return Unauthorized (401)
                    if (ctx.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/api") &&
                        ctx.Response.StatusCode == (int)HttpStatusCode.OK)
                    {
                        ctx.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        ctx.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.NotFound;
                    }
                    return Task.FromResult(0);
                }
            },
            CookieHttpOnly = true
        });
        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            routes.MapSpaFallbackRoute(
                name: "spa-fallback",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" });
        });
    }
}
```

I hope it makes sense.
Please let me know if I need to provide any additional information.
Any help in resolving this error will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is caused from `OnValidatePrincipal = SecurityStampValidator.ValidatePrincipalAsync`. [SecurityStampValidator.ValidatePrincipalAsync](https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/blob/aba7cf96b9ac7c910ee7db5e34fa7cf78516116a/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity/SecurityStampValidator.cs#L101) is an extension method and it requires `ISecurityStampValidator`. Since you don't use aspnet identity, there is no registered implementation for `ISecurityStampValidator`.

Remove this code or implement own `ISecurityStampValidator` and register it via dependency injection:

```
public class YourSecurityStampValidator : ISecurityStampValidator
{
    ....
}

// Register it 

services.TryAddScoped<ISecurityStampValidator, YourSecurityStampValidator>();
```